# How to use 'contents' to scrape the value I want?

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I am following this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-scrape-web-pages-with-beautiful-soup-and-python-3)
to scrape the data from the [website](https://web.archive.org/web/20121007172955/http://www.nga.gov/collection/anZ1.htm)

I want to scrape names, url, years and nationality and when I tried with below code

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import bs4


f = csv.writer(open('z_artist_names_assignment.csv', 'w'))
f.writerow(['N'])

pages = []

for i in range(1, 2):
    url = 'https://web.archive.org/web/20121007172955/https://www.nga.gov/collection/anZ' + str(i) + '.htm'
    pages.append(url)



for item in pages:
    page = requests.get(item,timeout=10)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    last_links = soup.find(class_='AlphaNav')
    last_links.decompose()

    artist_name_list = soup.find(class_='BodyText')
    artist_name_list_items = artist_name_list.find_all('a')

    nationality_list = soup.find(class_='BodyText')
    nationality_list_items = nationality_list.find_all('td')

    for artist_name in artist_name_list_items:
        names = artist_name.contents[0]
        links = 'https://web.archive.org' + artist_name.get('href')

    for nationality in nationality_list_items:
        nationality = nationality.contents[0]
        print(nationality)
```

print(nationality) returned
not only contents but also names and tabs like

```
<a href="/web/20121007172955/https://www.nga.gov/cgi-bin/tsearch?artistid=11630">Zabaglia, Niccola</a>
Italian, 1664 - 1750
<a href="/web/20121007172955/https://www.nga.gov/cgi-bin/tsearch?artistid=34202">Zaccone, Fabian</a>
American, 1910 - 1992
<a href="/web/20121007172955/https://www.nga.gov/cgi-bin/tsearch?artistid=3475">Zadkine, Ossip</a>
French, 1890 - 1967
```

I just want either 'Italian, 1664 - 1750' or 'Italian' or '1664 - 1750'. 
How can I use contents method to get these value?

this is the HTML

```
<tr valign="top"><td><a href="/web/20121007172955/http://www.nga.gov/cgi-bin/tsearch?artistid=3452">Zalce, Alfredo</a></td><td>Mexican, born 1908</td></tr>
```

Comment: There is an anchor "a" inside the "td" of nationalities, use this "nationality.a.contents[0]" instead of this "nationality.contents[0]"

Comment: Thank you! but it returned ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'
```
I tried 
nationality = nationality.a.contents[0] as well as nationality = nationality.a.contents

Comment: The information which you are looking for is not inside anchor tag. So please choose method which gives you text outside or in between two tags

Comment: You can try next sibling

Comment: It sounds like @ANDY_VAR is pointing you in the right direction.  You could also just go with what you have now in terms of what `nationality.contents[0]` returns and then post process that value to extract the part that you want.  It appears that you could just search the resulting string for `</a>\n`, and then grab all the characters that appear after that.  Using a regular expression could do this in a robust and generic way.

Comment: Thank you @ANDY_VAR and Steve !!
managed to get rid of unnecessary words by regular expression

Comment: you don't have to use regex, what i suggested above works, but some items are either empty or not exactly what you wanted, check for "a" before the assignment "if nationality.a:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to find all "tr" elements that contain artist's information instead of "td".

Below is example. Hope it helps!

```
entries = soup.find_all("tr", {"valign" : "top"})


links = ['https://web.archive.org{}'.format(entry.contents[0].a['href']) for entry in entries]
names = [entry.contents[0].text for entry in entries]
nationalities = [entry.contents[1] for entry in entries]
```

Comment: Lovely! This is much easier

Comment: @Trey I'm glad I could help!